# How to align textbox center horizontally on A4 size from C# reportviewer?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have tried to select textbox property TextAlign:center option. It also can't be align textbox center horizontally.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc;

// ...initialize 'doc'...

// Set the page size
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```